# iOS 11 NSPredicate search on Swift array crashing - NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, ios11, xcode9

I am using NSPredicate to filter an array in Swift. The problem is after updating to iOS 11 (Xcode 9 /w Swift 4), I keep getting a crash on the filter line. Here is the crash log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: >'[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key >value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Here is an example of the class that I have an array of:

```
final class Model: NSObject {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Here is the code that is crashing:

```
let myArray = [Model(name: "Jason"), Model(name: "Brian")]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == 'Jason'")
let filteredArray = myArray.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0)}
```

Question is why is this crashing now that I updated to iOS 11?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After fighting with this for a while, I finally came across the answer!

A subtlety of updating to Swift 4 is that classes that are subclasses of NSObject are no longer implicitly exposed to objective-c like they were before. Because of this, you need to explicitly annotate classes/functions with @objc. The compiler will notify you of places where the annotation is needed, but not in this case.

Ultimately because of this, the key-value lookup was no longer implicitly exposed to objective-c, which is needed to filter with NSPredicate. The code below fixes the crash!

**Solution 1**

```
extension Model {
    @objc override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        switch key {
        case "name":
            return name
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Alternative thanks to Uros19: Instead of implementing the above function, you could annotate the property directly with @objc (e.g., `@objc let name: String`). You lose a little bit of clarity as to why you are annotating the property with @objc, but this is only a small consideration.

I hope this saves some people time and frustration :)

Comment: Thanks for this. In case someone has model with more properties used for predicate and get this issue (like i did). You can just add @objc before property declaration. for example `@objc var name: String`, so you avoid long switch-case.

Comment: Nice, I will add this to my answer!! Thanks.

A small consideration to solving the problem this way is that you lose a little clarity as to why the property is directly annotated with `@objc`.