# HealthKit read works iOS 10 but not iOS 11

Tags: ios11, healthkit

I had this working before moving to iOS 11, but now the queries are not returning.  I had thought this might have something to do with Core Location, and have also been setting breakpoints.  But, so far, I'm not seeing anything that would have changed for HealthKit with iOS 11.  Does anyone reading this have suggestions for other items to check?

Comment: just adding to the initial post -- the obvious checks have been done: e.g. fast lane, podfile, and deployment targets are are all iOS 11, it also runs on device (again iOS 11), it just doesn't pull HK queries.  I'm not seeing any other posts on stack overflow for this, so it may ultimately be a silly error.  The WWDC videos also didn't have anything noted with regard to HK changes for iOS 11.

Comment: another add, I thought it might be with Swift 3 @objc interface options, but after quite a bit of working on that as an hypothesis for the issue, I'm pretty sure it's not the problem, there are some similarities to these posts, so passing it along in case it benefits anyone else reading this inquiry. Otherwise, I'm still trying to debug it.  The other information for debugging is that I can get single inquires to HK to come back in iOS 11, so it may well be related to lists. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371156/ios-11-nspredicate-search-on-swift-array-crashing-nsunknownkeyexception)